# Use a point wkt as a circle with openlayers

Tags: javascript, geometry, openlayers, openlayers-6, wkt

I am looking for a way to draw circles within the WKT format using Openlayers. I know that the WKT standard doesn’t support circles but someone said that you might be able to use a point wkt and then set a radius for it (for android but might work for other things as well). my question is thus how do I do that in Openlayers if it is possible?

link to what Tom said https://stackoverflow.com/a/58430532

This is how I made a polygon

```
     let polyFeature = new ol.format.WKT().readFeature(polygonWKT, {
    // Must use both projections in order to draw the feature with the wkt format
    dataProjection   : "EPSG:4326",
    featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() // Can at least get the standard projection and not have to fiddle with that
  });
  vectorSource.addFeature(polyFeature);
```

I’m asking this question to see if I can make the drawing/saving of the coordinates simpler. Right now, I have the coordinates in a string “coord1, coord2;” and have to split them when using a polygon and then convert them back into that string format when saving the coordinates.
With wkt I can just throw the string into the Openlayers function and I’m done so if I can kind of do the same with the circle then that would be great.

What I use
Openlayers v6 (some version of that)
vanilla js, php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always wrap the wkt in a JSON

```
'{"wkt":"POINT(28.625360369528934 77.2227479486792)"}'
```

You could optionally add a radius to indicate a circle

```
'{"wkt":"POINT(28.625360369528934 77.2227479486792)","radius":50}'
```

Then OpenLayers could parse the JSON string and convert a point with a radis to a circle

```
let json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
let polyFeature = new ol.format.WKT().readFeature(json.wkt, {
    dataProjection   : "EPSG:4326",
    featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()
});
if (json.radius && polyFeature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
    polyFeature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Circle(polyFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), json.radius));
}
vectorSource.addFeature(polyFeature);
```

Comment: That solution works great except I just changed the `.getGeometry().getCoordinbates` to `.getGeometry().getExtent` beacuse the getCoordinbates didn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: That was a typo, it should be `getCoordinates()`